# Calculate percentage of two inputs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, percentage

I want to calculate the percentage of two inputs which are total marks and obtained marks. When user fill these two inputs then in the percentage field i want to show the percentage automatically. I don't have the basic idea. Below is my controller

```
/** MyController.php */

public function store(ReportRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    if ($file = $request->file('photo_id'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }

    Report::create($input);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [computed Accessor attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in your `Request` model class:

```
/** Request.php */

public function getMarksPercentageAttribute
{
    return (float) $this->obtained_marks / $this->total_marks;
}
```

So when you create your records.. you can use this attribute:

```
$request = Request:first();
dd($request->marks_percentage); // 0.35 for example
```

PS: I'm assuming that `total_marks` and `obtained_marks` are columns of your table. In case this aren't the correct names, replace this with the ones you actually use.

---

Note, after the creation of the element you are returning back.. you could redirect to a `show` view for example. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects):

> #### Redirecting To Named Routes
>
> When you call the `redirect` helper with no parameters, an instance of
>   `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector` is returned, allowing you to call any
>   method on the  `Redirector` instance. For example, to generate a
>   `RedirectResponse` to a named route, you may use the `route` method:
>
> ```
> return redirect()->route('login');
> ```
>
> If your route has parameters, you may pass them as the second argument
>   to the route method:
>
> ```
> // For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}
>
> return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
> ```

Comment: How i can call that accessor in my controller ? I am confused there

Comment: @HasnainKahn the accesor is defined inside the model, and then you can use the access as any other model attribute: `$request->name`, `$user->marks_percentage`

Comment: @HasnainKahn check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pum_369j3S8) to understand this a little bit more.

Comment: @HCK missing parentheses **getMarksPercentageAttribute()**